# No file directory : java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android project and i wanna get the path of the uploaded picture from Camera or Gallery. All the permissions are set and I use this function to get the path but it seems `createNewFile()` is always ignored and i get `path=""` all the time.

```
public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

but i get a problem on the log 
[image]

Comment: Not sure if you aware of it but you can get a permission problem A). B) try to print the dir you store the file in, it's not hard coded so you have nothing to loose. Get more confident in your code by debugging, 4 hours of debugging every 2-3 days is okay per project.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There could be something the way you put together your filepath, but this is not viewable by your post. You could have missed giving permissions in the manifest, so the file is not created. 
Try this:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an External SD card in your phone as you are trying to access

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```